# search on ng-repeat by grouping the items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have created ng-repeat by group on which I am applying the filter, everything is working fine but the search functionality is not doing well, means when I am searching an item then its displaying the item but along with other group names are displaying which I want to hide.
when I search for an item then it should display the item along with the group and hide all the groups and other items.
Below is the

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in pops | groupBy: 'Location'">
  <div>
    <h4>{{ key }}</h4>
  </div>
  <br /><br /><br />


  <div ng-repeat="pop in value | filter: lookfor | orderBy: 'SortNo'">
    <div>
      <h4 style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">{{pop.EmpName}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Id: {{pop.EmpNo}}</p>

        <p>Desig: {{pop.Designation | titlecase}}</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

code.

Comment: Can u create a working fiddle

Comment: can you plz add js code too

Answer (score 0):

add your js code pls . Or you can create

```
<input ng-model="lookfor "/>
```

Comment: I need search to filter the correct item by hiding other groups. the search is searching but not hiding other groups.

Comment: **Jayant Patil** your jsfiddle should search the correct value under the correct group by displaying it and hiding other groups and items.

Comment: **Does any one know how to hide the other groups and items when searching for the item in ng-repeat based on grouping.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and add your filter code in it

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' placeholder='look for' ng-model='lookfor'>
```

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/73jyk0cv/)

Comment: **Jayant Patil** If you search for ssr in your jsfiddle then it will display other groups as well(0 and 2) which I dont want to see.

Comment: Yep thats what I was looking for thanks **Jayant Patil**

Comment: **Jayant Patil**, it has some bugs, when you type xyz in search then xyz is shown under 0 group.